# Word for the parameters of your question

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a specialized word that means "what you are specifically asking".

Take for example the question: "What is a green, herbivore reptile?" In that example, the thing (for which I'm looking the right word), is "color=green; diet=herbivore; class=reptile".

One word that has crossed my mind is "qualification", but I wonder if there are any better alternatives?

Comment: [microtaxonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species_problem)?

Comment: 'Category' is used to label a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest just using **parameters.**

> **[Parameter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parameter)** *(n)*
>
> any of a set of physical properties whose values
>   determine the characteristics or behavior of something

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Your word comes close to what I was looking for. Another word that I like is "specification".

Answer (score 0):

Variables.

A word from computing that is used to express the 'variable data' that comes back from a question or query.

Meaning: 'A data item that may take on more than one value during the runtime of a program' - eg 'black', 'green' , 'brown', or 'T. Rex', 'Stegosaurus', 'Triceratops', or 'dinosaur type'.

Examples:

- Please respond with any of these variables: green, brown, black
- Please give a answer for 'dinosaur' by completing these variables: colour=, diet=, class=.

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=variables+definition&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari